My parents don't allow me to put my phone in my bedroom... What should I do?
I am 23 years old, a fresh graduate, just started my full time job. tbh I don't get why my parents setting up strange rules like "DO NOT place your phone in bedroom when you sleep" I urged them for the reason, they just simply reply that our phone has radiation, bad for health... LOL ridiculous response. How could I persuade them in this issue or should I just simply ignore them and do whatever I want... I am no longer a student anymore...

Get a job and your own place. Then the rules are what you decide.

@SolarMike You are technically correct, but in the real world this is a bit odd from the parents.

Why the vote to close? This looks perfectly legit to me.

At 60-odd years old I have no desire to have my phone in the bedroom. I go there to sleep, not be woken up by other people wanting to bother me at night.

I'm going to tackle this using Transactional Analysis as a framework. Bear in mind that TA is only a framework for thinking about a complicated human situation. It's not a law of physics.
TA posits that we all have 3 personas we use for communication: the Parent, the Adult and the Child. Problems arise when Alice is trying to talk in Adult mode addressing Bob's Adult, but Bob is in Parent mode addressing Alice's Child. This is known as a "crossed transaction".
The Parent is further subdivided into Critical and Nurturing, while the Child is subdivided into Natural and Adapted.
Your parents here are firmly in Critical Parent mode, telling you what to do. What I'm less sure about is what mode you are in. "LOL ridiculous" and "do whatever I want" suggest that you are responding in Natural Child mode. As long as you stay in that mode the situation isn't going to resolve.
Your goal should be to shift the conversation into Adult-Adult mode. First you have to think about your own responses. Here are some suggestions, in no particular order:

Address the elephant in the room. You are an adult now, entitled to make your own decisions about how you live your life. You will certainly listen to any advice or suggestions your parents have, but you are no longer obliged to obey them.

Try asking questions like "What makes you think that?". Try to get them to discuss evidence and arguments in an adult way instead of trying to lay down the law.

Try giving them a face-saving way out. Would they be happier if your phone was in your room but not right next to the bed? Teach them about the inverse square law. Obviously its an unnecessary precaution, but its also a compromise they might feel able to live with.


Watch your tone of voice as well as the words: your Child is going to try to make "What makes you think that?" into "WHAT on EARTH makes you think THAT?!".
Also, be open to the possibility that their real concern is something else, and the radiation is just a pretext. Maybe they're really concerned about you looking at porn or terrorist propaganda or something. If they get evasive and and Parental about the radiation, try asking as an adult to an adult if this is really about radiation, or is there something else?
Your parents are going to try to keep things in Parent-Child mode because that's how they've dealt with you for the past 23 years and its a hard habit to break. You are going to need patience, determination and self-awareness to stop yourself switching back into Child mode in response. That will be hard, because just as they habitually use Parent mode to talk to you, you have a lifetime of responding in Child mode.
For more information on TA try "Games People Play" by Eric Berne.

Another possible concern could be screen-time (doomscrolling, gaming, etc) in bed, which could lead to less sleep and difficulties with going to sleep without external stimuli.
